# How do I duplicate VM properties to JUnit task in ANT?

Tags: ant, junit

As part of a JUnit test (executed from ANT) I need access to a fair few properties that are not only environment dependent, but can also change from one run to the next. In order to not affect any of numerous other devs that might use the same build.xml I wanted to define these properties on the command line with the `-D` flag (they're easily populated using a script). Reading about the `<junit>` task in ant I thought that these properties would be easily duplicated to the VM running the JUnit tests using the `clonevm` flag, but this doesn't seem to work. A simple `<echo>` before the `<junit>` call confirms the properties are set correctly, and I then execute the JUnit tests with the following:

```
<junit
    printsummary="on" showoutput="true" timeout="${tests.timeout.value}"
    haltonfailure="false" errorproperty="test.error.occurred"
    haltonerror="false" failureproperty="test.failure.occurred" forkmode="perTest"
    maxmemory="${project.junit.maxmemory}" clonevm="true">
    <jvmarg line="${project.test.vmargs}"/>
    <sysproperty key="java.io.tmpdir" value="${java.io.tmpdir}"/>
    <formatter type="xml" usefile="true"/>
    <classpath>
        <path refid="build.test.classpath"/>
    </classpath>
    <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${test.rpt.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${test.bin.dir}">
            <include name="**/${test.classes.run}.class"/>
            <includesfile name="${test.run.includesfile}"/>
            <!-- ignore inner classes -->
            <exclude name="**/*$*.class"/>
        </fileset>
    </batchtest>
</junit>
```

I then attempt to read a property value using `System.getProperty("property");` but always get null. I assume I must be doing something wrong so that the properties aren't sent to the JUnit VM, or I'm not reading it correctly. Any ideas? I guess I could work around the problem (use the script to write a temporary properties file, then read that from the test), but I'd still like to know how to do this if it's even possible.

Comment: Try using a nested syspropertyset element. See junit documentation: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html

Comment: That sounds feasible. Unfortunately it's not a solution I'd be able to keep (the snippet of build script I've pasted is not controlled by me, I can only set the various parameters), but I can certainly test it and see if it works.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor I've had a look at it and found that using `<propertyset id="test.sysproperties" negate="true"/>` along with `<syspropertyset refid="test.sysproperties"/>` was very useful as it easily makes all properties available in ANT available in the JUnit test. I might pass that on to the build team so I can make use of it later. Thanks a lot. You should put that down as an answer so I can give you points for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a nested syspropertyset element.

See [junit documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html)